# Looping in Subplots produced charts twice

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have the following code and am trying to loop through to generate three sets of 2x2 plots.

```
from IPython.display import display

def generate_subplots (i):


    fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, figsize = (11, 11))

    plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=0.3, hspace=0.3)

    p1.plot(kind='barh', ax=axs[0, 0]).invert_yaxis()
    p3.plot(kind='barh', ax=axs[0, 1]).invert_yaxis()
    p2.plot(kind='barh', ax=axs[1, 0]).invert_yaxis()
    p4.plot(kind='barh', ax=axs[1, 1]).invert_yaxis()

    axs[0, 0].set_xlim(0, 1)
    axs[0, 1].set_xlim(0, 1)
    axs[1, 0].set_xlim(0, 1)
    axs[1, 1].set_xlim(0, 1)

    axs[0, 0].set_title('Title A')
    axs[0, 1].set_title('Title B')
    axs[1, 0].set_title('Title C')
    axs[1, 1].set_title('Title D')

    display ('Users who have at least ' + str(i+1) + ' cell phones')

    display (fig)


for i in range(0, 3):

    d1 = df[df3['varx'] > i)]
    d2 = df[df3['varx'] > i)]
    d3 = df[df3['varx'] > i)]
    d4 = df[df3['varx'] > i)]

    p1 = d1.var1.value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()
    p2 = d2.var1.value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index() 
    p3 = d3.var1.value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index() 
    p4 = d4.var1.value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index() 

    generate_subplots(i)
```

I tried using the 'display' function, but now it's printing the sets of charts twice. It goes like this:

Users who have at least 1 cell phones

Set 1 of 2x2 charts

Users who have at least 2 cell phones

Set 2 of 2x2 charts

Users who have at least 3 cell phones

Set 3 of 2x2 charts

Set 1 of 2x2 charts

Set 2 of 2x2 charts

Set 3 of 2x2 charts

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have `generate_subplots` return the figure object and capture its output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're working in a jupyter notebook or similar environment. If so, you don't really need the `display` function.

```
def generate_subplots(i, p1, p2, p3, p4):
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, figsize=(11, 11))

    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3, hspace=0.3)

    for ax, p, letter in zip(axs.flat, (p1, p3, p2, p4), list('ABCD')):
        p.plot(kind='barh', ax=ax)
        ax.invert_yaxis()
        ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
        ax.set_title('Title {}'.format(letter))

    print('Users who have at least {} cell phones'.format(i))
    return fig


for i in range(0, 3):
    p_df = [
        df.loc[df['varx'] > i, 'var1'].value_counts(normalize=True)
        for df in [df1, df2, df3, df4]
    ]
    fig = generate_subplots(i, *p_df)
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try. I am a beginner to python. Would you mind explaining what ‘ax.flat’ and ‘*p_df’ do, if it’s not much trouble?

Comment: @RJL try them out in a notebook. `axs.flat` iterates through your 2-D array of axes as if it was a 1-D vector. `p_df` is a list of dataframe that replaces your sequentially named dataframe variables.

Comment: Sorry on p_df, what I don’t understand is what the asterisk does when calling the function. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @RJL search around for "python argument unpacking"